# What is the difference between もらう and もらえる in this sentence?

Tags: sentence, giving-and-receiving

> 新年から運動につきあってもらえるのはありがてぇんだけど

I understand the speaker is grateful because the other character accompanied him from the beginning of the new year to do exercise, but what does もらえる communicate differently from using もらう here?

Comment: Can you correct もらる to もらう?

Answer (score 2):

Actually in this context, the dictionary form もらう is nearly unusable. The vanilla もらう has a connotation that the said action is granted, or expected. It is okay if you use it in the past form, or in front of a third party, but sounds as if you are "forcing" the hearer when spoken towards themselves.

Thus if you want to tell the other you are "grateful", not only the fact being "beneficial" to you, you need to say like you're glad that you *can* (= be lucky to; be accepted to) have them to do something, and that is what the potential form does here.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure, but could it be that it expresses gratefulness for being able to come instead of direct gratefulness for coming?

Answer (score 0):

> あなたは私について来てもらいます。これは命令です。

As the above example shows, VERBてもらう can be used about an event that is predetermined, often by you.

> 奴には死んでもらった。

This means you killed him.

> 新年から運動につきあってもらえるのはありがてぇんだけど

〜てもらえる in this case makes it clear that it is at the discretion of the person who keeps you company (or possibly someone else's), and not at yours, to do so.